# Anonymous Identification cookie change for every request

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, cookies, asp.net-mvc-5

For the last couple of days I'm trying to resolve a problem in my MVC 5 web application related to the anonymous identification module.
I enabled the anonymous identification by adding the following line to Web.config:

```
<anonymousIdentification enabled="true" />
```

The problem is that the cookie used by the module changes every time the browser sends a request:

```
.ASPXANONYMOUS=6yylwpA5baKlbP-ntBra3pA1vr1y5kXp...
```

After refreshing the page the cookie changes to:

```
.ASPXANONYMOUS=s3-AlVJNimP5NrDI1PLWc8RK720RTeNY....
```

And so on and so forth. 
What's interesting is that anonymous identification works perfectly fine in our test environment and keeps the value of the cookie consistent across multiple requests. But deploying the same code to production results in this strange behavior, so I suspect a configuration issue in IIS. Both environments use IIS 8.5. 
Any idea what I'm missing here?

Comment: Were you able to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You have likely moved on but I noticed this while in development on some MVC5 applications.

If you use a valid hostname / domain / IP and not 127.0.0.1, it shouldn't recreate the `.ASPXANONYMOUS` cookie every request.

On a side note, you can do a lot of edits to the anonymous cookie by applying attributes to the configuration.

For example, the following would only set the anonymous cookie for an hour:

```
<anonymousIdentification 
            enabled="true" 
            cookieName=".ASPXANONYMOUS"
            cookieTimeout="60"
            />
```

Link to documentation on the [anonymousIdentification](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/91ka2e6a(v=vs.91)) element for more info.